# Why does Taq polymerase add 3' adenine overhangs?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, pcr, polymerase

Is there a mechanism for the preference of *Taq* polymerase to add a non-templated 3' adenine (overhang) instead of other bases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-templated terminal addition by certain DNA polymerases is apparently dependent on the base stacking between the incoming base and the existing duplex ([Fiala et al., 2007](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmb.2006.10.008)*). This was verified by using a non-base-pairing (but better stacking) nucleotide analogue called deoxyribo pyrene nucleoside triphosphate (dPTP). Adenine seems to have a higher efficiency of base stacking compared to other three bases: 
 `A (1.0), G (0.7), T (0.6), and C (0.5)`

It was also verified that the preference for dATP did not depend much on the terminal base-pair of the duplex with the incorporation probabilities being:

`79% dATP 16% dTTP, 3% dCTP, and 2% dGTP` when the last base pair is A-T (A is 3'), and
`81% dATP, 8% dTTP, 8% dCTP, and 2% dGTP` when the last base pair is G-C

---

<sup>Fiala, Kevin A., et al. "[**Mechanism of template-independent nucleotide incorporation catalyzed by a template-dependent DNA polymerase**.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jmb.2006.10.008)" *Journal of Molecular Biology* 365.3 (2007): 590-602.</sup>

*They had used the Dpo4 polymerase from *Sulfolobus solfataricus* as a model because it is a known lesion bypass polymerase and its kinetics and structure are well studied.